# For Loop print results line by line

Tags: php, wordpress, for-loop

Hi i have following php codes(part of my full code):

```
$instance = $old_instance;
$instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
$instance['serisname1'] = $new_instance['serisname1'];
$instance['serisname2'] = $new_instance['serisname2'];  
$instance['serisname3'] = $new_instance['serisname3'];
$instance['serisname4'] = $new_instance['serisname4'];  
$instance['serisname5'] = $new_instance['serisname5'];
$instance['serisname6'] = $new_instance['serisname6'];  
$instance['serisname7'] = $new_instance['serisname7'];
$instance['serisname8'] = $new_instance['serisname8'];              
$instance['serisname9'] = $new_instance['serisname9'];
$instance['serisname10'] = $new_instance['serisname10'];    
$instance['serisname11'] = $new_instance['serisname11'];
$instance['serisname12'] = $new_instance['serisname12'];    
$instance['serisname13'] = $new_instance['serisname13'];
$instance['serisname14'] = $new_instance['serisname14'];    
$instance['serisname15'] = $new_instance['serisname15'];        
return $instance;

for($x = 1; $x <= 15; $x++)
$serisname = $instance[serisname.$x];
$items[] = $serisname;
print_r($items);
```

my export :

```
array ( [0] => The Flash )
```

i want its be like :

```
array ( [0] => The Flash [1] => Arrow [2] => Game Of Throne and etc...)
```

the problem is its only echo last result but i want its echo every 15 results line by line.

Comment: Are you sure that's what the code you pasted does? I'm trying it in https://www.tehplayground.com/EkJpwKaUdVxobNOk and it outputs nothing at all, probably because it hits the return statement before it hits `print_r`.

Comment: actually its part of my codes from my wordpress widget.my full codes ha lot of lines and include lot of stuff so i cant paste all of them.

Answer (score 0):

If I understead your question correctly, you can try this:

```
$count = 0;

for($x = 0; $x <= count($instance); $x++) {
  $items[$x][] = $instance[serisname.$x];
  if($count == 15) {
    $count = 0;
  }
}
```

Maybe can include the instance before the loop in your question so we can replicate the array?

Answer (score 0):

```
for($x = 1; $x <= 15; $x++){
    $serisname = $instance['serisname'.$x];
    $items[] = $serisname;
}
print_r($items);
```